# Data Binding features not showing in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, architecture, android-viewbinding

I am trying all these methods in the latest android studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1, but the build feature, data binding, and view Binding options are not showing before and after adding this **annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.1** dependency.

I have tried using different dependencies, but the IntelliSense window for view Binding, data Binding, or buildFeature{ } options not showing. I need help regarding this issue. Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: Issue resolved by adding these lines in gradle.properties without adding buildFeature in app level module.

android.defaults.buildfeatures.viewbinding=true
android.defaults.buildfeatures.databinding=true

Answer (score 2):

you can add viewbinding and databinding to your gradle file like this:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
    viewBinding true
}
```

Comment: This is not working in latest android studio

Comment: Just copy and paste below kotlinOptions, it's works! thanks!